# Which design pattern(s) to use for a dynamic/modular "event" system?

Tags: design-patterns, dynamic, modularity

I'm trying to create a kind of event-system (in lack of a better definition) for a game I'm making. What I need to do, is to have a set of (hardcoded) 'core' functions, which I can link together in a arbitrary way and define as an "event", which I can then  execute with some arbitrary parameters.

These "events" would be relatively simple if they were hardcoded, f.ex.

```
hardcodedEvent(int this, int that){
    coreFunc1(this);
    coreFunc2(that);
    coreFunc3(coreFunc4(this + that));
    //etc...
}
```

But the entire point is that they need to be dynamic and modular, so that you would be able to, in theory, construct and represent these events in a flow-chart/diagram like way (example: 
[flow-chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmdNU.png) editor from 3d software)

Eventually, I would need these events to be serializable, so that I could save and load them as a file or to/from a database.

I've looked at Callback, Command, Observer and State machine patterns, but I don't know which one(s) would best suited for something like this, and I havn't worked much with any of them before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me you have in mind exactly the kind of design pattern that would be useful for your problem. It's certainly only a matter of combining them.

If I understand well, you are trying to do a game with some events (messageing, information exchange, ...) and with some save/load/log logic (file save, database, ...) at some point.

**State** : For a state machine behavior, with modular states, seems suited for the game according to your "flow chart" description but less for the event-system

**Observer** : For a publish/subscribe logic (information sharing, ...)

**Callback** : For a loose coupled logging-system (sync'ing things, log to file)

**Command** : For encapsulating request as objects, maybe the less useful here

I would add two others to the list :

**Decorator** : Because your game components, events seems to be "chainable" in a modular way (ie : chaining core functions to make more evolved ones)

**Builder** : For the part where you want to load a game from a file - It could crawl your file and recreate the game in the state it has been saved, encapsulating a heavy loading logic...

Hope it helps.